# How do I use d3.js commands to populate two divs one on top of the other?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

[image]

Hello. Can anyone help me understand. I am trying to understand d3 commands for populating divs.
So in the html code I have put two divs on top of each other
and below in the script code I use two d3 variable commands to populate each div with 4 rectangles
the code works up to var **svgContainer2** , which is almost identical to **var svgContainer**
not sure why **svgContainer2** not populating the 2nd div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="svg_area"></div> <!-- area 1 -->
    <div id="svg_area2"></div> <!-- area 2 -->
</body>
</html>
<script>

var svgContainer = d3.select("#svg_area").append("svg")
    .attr("height", 800)
    .attr("width", 800);

var myRectangle1 = svgContainer.append("rect") // top left
    .attr("x", 50)  // in relation to left of svg container
    .attr("y", 50)  // in relation to top of svg container
    .attr("height", 100)  //
    .attr("width", 100)  //
    .attr("fill", "blue")  //

var myRectangle2 = svgContainer.append("rect") // bottom right
    .attr("x", 200)  //
    .attr("y", 200)  //
    .attr("height", 100)  //
    .attr("width", 100)  //
    .attr("fill", "red")  //

var myRectangle3 = svgContainer.append("rect") // top right
    .attr("x", 200)  //
    .attr("y", 50)  //
    .attr("height", 100)  //
    .attr("width", 100)  //
    .attr("fill", "green")  //

var myRectangle4 = svgContainer.append("rect") // bottom left
    .attr("x", 50)  //
    .attr("y", 200)  //
    .attr("height", 100)  //
    .attr("width", 100)  //
    .attr("fill", "yellow")  //

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var svgContainer2 = d3.select("#svg_area2").append("svg")
    .attr("height", 800)
    .attr("width", 800);

var myRectangle5 = svgContainer2.append("rect") // top left
    .attr("x", 50)  // in relation to left of svg container
    .attr("y", 50)  // in relation to top of svg container
    .attr("height", 100)  //
    .attr("width", 100)  //
    .attr("fill", "blue")  //

var myRectangle6 = svgContainer2.append("rect") // bottom right
    .attr("x", 200)  //
    .attr("y", 200)  //
    .attr("height", 100)  //
    .attr("width", 100)  //
    .attr("fill", "red")  //

var myRectangle7 = svgContainer2.append("rect") // top right
    .attr("x", 200)  //
    .attr("y", 50)  //
    .attr("height", 100)  //
    .attr("width", 100)  //
    .attr("fill", "green")  //

var myCircle8 = svgContainer2.append("rect") // bottom left
    .attr("x", 50)  //
    .attr("y", 200)  //
    .attr("height", 100)  //
    .attr("width", 100)  //
    .attr("fill", "yellow")  //

</script>
```

Comment: Your `script` tag is out side your `body` tag.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for the suggestion. I have tried your idea, but it doesn't fix. It is my understanding that script can also be run outside the body tag, because it allows the body to load first and then the script load next.

Comment: The tag cannot be put outside the body tag. It should be put at the **end** of the body tag so that it is run after the document has loaded.

Comment: I have run your code, and both areas look the same

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have realized my error, didn't realize I could scroll down and see the second div, I've adjusted the height of the first div and can now see both. Sorry a rookie error.

Comment: :D no worries. We've all been there